# jQuery detach/reattach input field mobile focus issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, input, detach

I have a search `<input>` box that I want to `detach()` from a position and reattach (read: `appendTo()`) to place in a mobile menu. So I'm using something like:

```
var searchform = $('.search__form');

searchform.appendTo('.newposition');
```

This correctly moves the element, however, on mobile/tablet devices (all I've tested regardless of OS and browser) it makes it impossible to `:focus` in the `<input>` box. If you click into the search box then the keyboard for that device appears but then hides within a second making it impossible to use.

Does anyone have any idea why this is occuring?

Comment: But on which context do you call your snippet to move input element in DOM? Inside any event handler or what?

Comment: It's in a function that is executed on document.ready()